# Android CustomListAdapter with Image loaded from URL in Sliding Menu

Tags: java, android

UPDATE

As notice Justin.W I pass imageView to imageLoader

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
```

But still first time open hangs on first open. Because it's wait for image loaded.

I'm developing sliding menu and fill it with CustomListAdapter (image and text). First row has dynamic data, image and user name. Problem that getView method fires only when I toggle menu to show first time, so image loads and hangs menu opening. This is getView method in CustomListAdapter class

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null,true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menuItem);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if(position==0){
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logInPref", 0);
        String name = preferences.getString("name", null);
        String image = preferences.getString("image", null);
        txtTitle.setText(name);
        if(image!=null){
            img = imageView;
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            String imageUrl = "http://doktormobil.ru/cms/avatar2/min/"+image;
            new LoadImage().execute(imageUrl);
        }
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    }
    return rowView;
};
```

Is there any way to load image from URL without opening sliding menu, so on first time menu opening image is already loaded and shown?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the images on a background thread and store it in LruCache before you toggle the menu then.

Information about bitmap caching using LruCache here:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Or you should also pass the imageView to LoadImage() AsyncTask and have the background thread assign the bitmap to the imageView in the background thread instead of locking up the UI thread.

Comment: I'm loading image in background

Comment: pass imageView to LoadImage(imageView).execute(urlPath). Then do imageView.setImageResource(bitmapHere) under postExecute();

Comment: No luck( Drag animation on first open still hangs.